# ggproto: How to access non-aesthetic parameter values in compute_layer()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggproto

I'm trying to make new geoms and stats. I tried a StatChull code from this [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html). **My goal is to manipulate an external parameter which is not an aesthetic value.** Something like this:

```
stat_custom(data = df, mapping = aes(x = xval, y = val), myparam = myval, geom = "custom")
```

The thing is, when I make custom stat with `compute_group()`, I can get the custom parameter. As soon as I change `compute_group()` to `compute_layer()`, program stops working.

Here is a working program for stat_chull():

```
StatChull <- ggproto("StatChull", Stat,
                     compute_group = function(self, data, scales, params, na.rm, myparam) {
                       message("My param has value ", myparam)
                       # browser()
                       data[chull(data$x, data$y), , drop = FALSE]
                     },

                     required_aes = c("x", "y")
)

stat_chull <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "polygon",
                       position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, myparam = "", show.legend = NA, 
                       inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) {
  layer(
    stat = StatChull, data = data, mapping = mapping, geom = geom, 
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(na.rm = na.rm, myparam = myparam, ...)
  )
}

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_chull(fill = NA, colour = "black", myparam = "myval")
```

This prints on console:

```
My param has value myval
```

This programs errors when I change **compute_group()** to **compute_layer()**:

```
StatChull <- ggproto("StatChull", Stat,
                     compute_layer = function(self, data, scales, params, na.rm, myparam) {
                       message("My param has value ", myparam)
                       # browser()
                       data[chull(data$x, data$y), , drop = FALSE]
                     },

                     required_aes = c("x", "y")
)

stat_chull <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "polygon",
                       position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, myparam = "", show.legend = NA, 
                       inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) {
  layer(
    stat = StatChull, data = data, mapping = mapping, geom = geom, 
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(na.rm = na.rm, myparam = myparam, ...)
  )
}

ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_chull(fill = NA, colour = "black", myparam = "myval")
```

This prints on console:

```
Warning: Ignoring unknown parameters: myparam

Error in message("My param has value ", myparam): argument "myparam" is missing, with no default
```

Can anyone tell me how do I access parameter values in `compute_layer()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Explanation

All `geom_*()` and `stat_*()` functions are wrappers around `layer()`. If we examine the code in that, we can see that the parameter values associated with a Stat are captured in `stat_params`, which is obtained via `stat$parameters(TRUE)`, where `stat` refers to the specific Stat* ggproto object:

```
> layer
function (geom = NULL, stat = NULL, data = NULL, mapping = NULL, 
    position = NULL, params = list(), inherit.aes = TRUE, check.aes = TRUE, 
    check.param = TRUE, show.legend = NA) 
{
    ... # omitted
    params <- rename_aes(params)
    aes_params <- params[intersect(names(params), geom$aesthetics())]
    geom_params <- params[intersect(names(params), geom$parameters(TRUE))]
    stat_params <- params[intersect(names(params), stat$parameters(TRUE))]
    all <- c(geom$parameters(TRUE), stat$parameters(TRUE), geom$aesthetics())
    extra_param <- setdiff(names(params), all)
    if (check.param && length(extra_param) > 0) {
        warning("Ignoring unknown parameters: ", paste(extra_param, 
            collapse = ", "), call. = FALSE, immediate. = TRUE)
    }
    extra_aes <- setdiff(mapped_aesthetics(mapping), c(geom$aesthetics(), 
        stat$aesthetics()))
    if (check.aes && length(extra_aes) > 0) {
        warning("Ignoring unknown aesthetics: ", paste(extra_aes, 
            collapse = ", "), call. = FALSE, immediate. = TRUE)
    }
    ggproto("LayerInstance", Layer, geom = geom, geom_params = geom_params, 
        stat = stat, stat_params = stat_params, data = data, 
        mapping = mapping, aes_params = aes_params, position = position, 
        inherit.aes = inherit.aes, show.legend = show.legend)
}
```

StatChull inherits from Stat with no change to its parameter function, which would be:

```
> Stat$parameters
<ggproto method>
  <Wrapper function>
    function (...) 
f(..., self = self)

  <Inner function (f)>
    function (self, extra = FALSE) 
{
    panel_args <- names(ggproto_formals(self$compute_panel))
    group_args <- names(ggproto_formals(self$compute_group))
    args <- if ("..." %in% panel_args) 
        group_args
    else panel_args
    args <- setdiff(args, names(ggproto_formals(Stat$compute_group)))
    if (extra) {
        args <- union(args, self$extra_params)
    }
    args
}
```

## Solution

From the above, we can tell that `stat$parameters` depends on the function arguments listed in the relevant Stat*'s `compute_panel` / `compute_group` functions. As such, the following will work:

```
StatChull <- ggproto("StatChull", 
                     Stat,
                     compute_layer = function (self, data, params, layout) {
                       message("My param has value ", params$myparam)
                       data[chull(data$x, data$y), , drop = FALSE]
                     },
                     compute_group = function(self, data, scales, na.rm, myparam) {
                       # this function is never triggered, but defined here
                       # in order for myparam to be included in stat_params
                     },
                     required_aes = c("x", "y")
)

# no change to stat_chull
```

Note that we've defined a trivial `compute_group` function for StatChull. This function is never triggered since `compute_layer` returns a dataset directly (under normal circumstances for Stat, `compute_group` is triggered by `compute_panel`, which is in turn triggered by `compute_layer`), but since it does include `myparam` as one of its function arguments, `myparam` is now recognized as one of the parameter values in `params`.

(You can also achieve the same result by defining a trivial `compute_panel` function instead, too.)

Demonstration:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_chull(fill = NA, colour = "black", myparam = "myval")
```

[image: plot]

```
My param has value myval
```